# How to run numeric keys for numeric entry for asp.net textbox?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, keyboard, integer

I've a textbox that should be entered just numeric. It has a js function.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPrintCount" runat="server" MaxLength="2" Style="width: 30px" onkeydown="return CheckNumeric(event);" />
```

```js
function CheckNumeric(e) {
  if (window.event) { // IE
    if ((e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57) & e.keyCode != 8) {
      event.returnValue = false;
      return false;
    }
  } else { // Firefox
    if ((e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) & e.which != 8) {
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

However, numeric keypad is not working with this function. Only the other numeric keys work on keyboard.

Is there something I have forgotten for this? How can I run the numeric keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there something I have forgotten for this? How can I run the numeric keys?

The keycodes are different. The numbers are from `48` to `57`. The numpads are from `96` to `105`.

> I've a textbox that should be entered just numeric.

But instead of testing the keys, you should test that the value is an integer:

```
function isInteger(value) {
  return value === parseInt(value, 10);
}

function CheckNumeric(e) {
  if (window.event) { // IE
    if (!isInteger(window.event.srcElement.value)) {
      event.returnValue = false;
      return false;
    }
  } else { // Firefox, Chrome, Edge, Safari, Opera, etc
    if (!isInteger(e.target.value)) {
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response but It also allows £, ^, $ etc. characters.

Answer (score 1):

you should use `onkeypress` event instead of `onkeydown`. change your desing to this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPrintCount" runat="server" MaxLength="2" Style="width: 30px" onkeypress="return CheckNumeric(event);" />
```